# I want to implement a searchbar for recycler view in a fragment. I have tried the below code in my fragment but it is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, searchbar

I have tried the below code in my fragment class but it is not working and also not showing any error,i have given both the adapter class code and fragment class code please tell where i have mistaken what is happening that when i run the code it is not showing even the search bar on the fragment

//Fragment class code

```
public class PharmacyPatientFragment extends Fragment {
    PharmacyAdapter Adapter;
    private FragmentPharmacyPatientBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentPharmacyPatientBinding.inflate(inflater);
        binding.recylerviewPharmacy.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        Adapter = new PharmacyAdapter(dataqueue());
        binding.recylerviewPharmacy.setAdapter(Adapter);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {

        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_option, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                Adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

    }

    public ArrayList<PharmacyDataModel> dataqueue() {
        ArrayList<PharmacyDataModel> holder = new ArrayList<>();
        PharmacyDataModel obj1 = new PharmacyDataModel();
        obj1.setMed_name("Remdesiver");
        obj1.setMfg_change("HealthBio Pharmaceuticals");
        obj1.setPrice_change("10000Rs.");
        obj1.setQty_change("1 unit");
        obj1.setImg_name(R.drawable.remdesiver);
        holder.add(obj1);
        PharmacyDataModel obj2 = new PharmacyDataModel();
        obj2.setMed_name("PPE Kits");
        obj2.setMfg_change("HealthBio Pharmaceuticals");
        obj2.setPrice_change("800Rs.");
        obj2.setQty_change("1 unit");
        obj2.setImg_name(R.drawable.ppe);
        holder.add(obj2);
        PharmacyDataModel obj3 = new PharmacyDataModel();
        obj3.setMed_name("Masks");
        obj3.setMfg_change("HealthBio Pharmaceuticals");
        obj3.setPrice_change("100Rs.");
        obj3.setQty_change("1 unit");
        obj3.setImg_name(R.drawable.masks);
        holder.add(obj3);
        PharmacyDataModel obj4 = new PharmacyDataModel();
        obj4.setMed_name("Gloves");
        obj4.setMfg_change("HealthBio Pharmaceuticals");
        obj4.setPrice_change("50Rs.");
        obj4.setQty_change("1 unit");
        obj4.setImg_name(R.drawable.gloves);
        holder.add(obj4);
        PharmacyDataModel obj5 = new PharmacyDataModel();
        obj5.setMed_name("Gluconate tablets");
        obj5.setMfg_change("HealthBio Pharmaceuticals");
        obj5.setPrice_change("100Rs.");
        obj5.setQty_change("20 tablets");
        obj5.setImg_name(R.drawable.gluconate);
        holder.add(obj5);
        PharmacyDataModel obj6 = new PharmacyDataModel();
        obj6.setMed_name("Sugar Free");
        obj6.setMfg_change("HealthBio Pharmaceuticals");
        obj6.setPrice_change("250Rs.");
        obj6.setQty_change("1 unit");
        obj6.setImg_name(R.drawable.sugarfree);
        holder.add(obj6);
        PharmacyDataModel obj7 = new PharmacyDataModel();
        obj7.setMed_name("Zincovit");
        obj7.setMfg_change("HealthBio Pharmaceuticals");
        obj7.setPrice_change("150Rs.");
        obj7.setQty_change("1 unit");
        obj7.setImg_name(R.drawable.zincovit);
        holder.add(obj7);

        return holder;
    }


}
```

//Adapter class code

```
public class PharmacyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PharmacyViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    ArrayList<PharmacyDataModel> data;
    ArrayList<PharmacyDataModel> datacopy;
    private final Filter dataFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            ArrayList<PharmacyDataModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(datacopy);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (PharmacyDataModel item : datacopy) {
                    if (item.getMed_name().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            data.clear();
            data.addAll((ArrayList) filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public PharmacyAdapter(ArrayList<PharmacyDataModel> data) {
        this.data = data;
        datacopy = new ArrayList<>(data);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PharmacyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlepharmacy_row, parent, false);
        return new PharmacyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PharmacyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textMedName.setText(data.get(position).getMed_name());
        holder.textMedQty.setText(data.get(position).getQty_change());
        holder.textMedPrice.setText(data.get(position).getPrice_change());
        holder.textMedMfg.setText(data.get(position).getMfg_change());
        holder.imageMed.setImageResource(data.get(position).getImg_name());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return dataFilter;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the error? Where are seeing it? That's not a error from Python. And that way or using `join` would be the simplest. The main issue with your way here is that it leaves a trailing space, but that's easy to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert a loop counter to string using `str`, include the value in a list, use the multiplication operator to repeat the value in the list, and then use the string `join` function to insert the spaces. Here's an example. If you want to start with `1 1 1` and not just `1` like I do here, then `print(' '.join((i + 2) * [str(i)]))` instead of what is shown

```
>>> for i in range(1, 6):
...     print(' '.join(i*[str(i)]))
...
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```